# curlftpfs interprets file date stamp incorrectly

Tags: datetime, curl, ftp, curlftpfs

If I log into my ftp server with `ftp myserver.com` and create a directory with:

```
ftp> mkdir testdir
```

The directory will have the correct time stamp.  I can verify this with:

```
ftp> ls
```

I can also log into the server and run `ls` and get the same time stamp for the directory (or file).

However, when I do this from a mounted curlftpfs, the `ls` listing shows the file an hour in the future.  The server has the correct time stamp, but there's problems with the time stamp of the files being using the curlftpfs mount.

This causes problems with my sync, backup, and programming applications.

Can someone advise me of where to look to try to resolve this issue with curlftpfs mounts?

By the way, the gvfs mounts has the same time stamp problem.

I suspected it might be a problem with Ubuntu's timezone setting, even though everything else (my clocks, alarms, email, etc) works properly with the correct timezone.  I even ran the timezone configuration to ensure the timezone was correct:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

I still have the same problem with the curlftpfs and gvfs mounts.